# Overlay Electron

Tags: javascript, overlay, desktop, electron

I am wondering if it is possible to overlay an application made in electron over a game. essentially similar to how steam overlays in games.

I want this because we have made a timer web app that times tasks and are debating making it an overlay if possible. to time certain events in games that reoccur

I have no idea if this can be achieved but it is something high on our list. Any example of how this can be achieved or has anyone done this before.

Thanks,

Kieran

Comment: The comparison with steam is not the right direction to think, unless you want to tie into DirectX or OpenGL .. The electron spec and docs are sparse on this kind of topic suggesting, it's not nativley supported and would need to be an extension for Electron..

Comment: Steams ties directly into the rendering engine, you really can't do this easily with electron. It is possible to make an electron window transparent, see this issue for the discussion: https://github.com/atom/electron/issues/381 so your best bet would probably be doing that and locking the window position to the game window.

Comment: If hooking Direct3D/OpenGL is not an option - try this  https://stackoverflow.com/a/67110394/533976

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To draw overlay in a game, you need hook Direct3D or OpenGL api according to which the game use.

And before present call(in D3D), you can draw your own stuff on a swapchain surface.

To control a overlay window in game, you need use Windows message hook and some other stuff.

And you should carefully manage all the windows in your program that draws in game.

There is a hook project [Direct3DHook](https://github.com/spazzarama/Direct3DHook), it's written in C#, but it will be easy to write in C++.

If you want to write a good overlay engine, there will be plenty details to consider.

[Overwolf](http://www.overwolf.com/) is a overlay app platform, I write an overlay project at work which took about two month to be something approximate.

I have written a project,  https://github.com/hiitiger/goverlay.

Comment: the blog link on your GitHub repo appears to be down