# Electron keeps getting selected when win.show();

Tags: node.js, reactjs, electron

I am currently writing a project together with Electron, I am creating custom notifications and I have basically put down the design and the animations I want. It is all working (Thank god!). However, I do experience one problem.

I have structured my notification app in such way that the notification window gets hidden after five seconds, and it is shown whenever it gets data. This works, the issue at hand is that everytime a notification pops up, the window is selected. This could be and issue if you were ingame because it would either minimize the game itself or select the window and you'd have to select the game again if in borderless.

Is there anyway for me to get the notifications to launch without the window itself gets selected. Kind of like an overlay.

Window spec:
`// Construct the BrowserWindow itself
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    height: resHeight,
    width: resWidth,
    frame: false,
    alwaysOnTop: false,
    transparent: true,
    resizable: false,
    movable: false,
    show: false,
    skipTaskbar: true
  });`

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably make another browser window, and put the notification in that. Alternatively, you could give [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35608927/overlay-electron) a try.

Comment: Hey! I saw that post, however that involves Direct3D hooks and from what I understand you have to target the specific game. Right now I am only rendering one window, once. Then I am switching between win.hide(); and win.show(); Thing is I want it to show but the window itself keeps getting selected like if you switch between windows. Which removes control of for example a game until selected again.

Comment: @DCBN ah, well have you given [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-notify), or [this](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/desktop-environment-integration.md), or maybe [this](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/262). Sorry if these don't help you! I'll try to get you sorted out! Also, sorry for being a bit slow to reply, was sleeping!

Comment: Hey, no worries! Thank you for taking your time to help, I'll give them a try. I'll be back soon!

Comment: Hey again! I was really fascinated about electron-notify, thanks for the tip. It works just as I wanted my notification to. So I will probably study the code and hopefully it won't be too much of an hassle. I thank you once again @willyb321 :D

Comment: @DCBN glad that worked for you!! Also glad I could help!