# Electron app that is screen overlay catching and passing user actions

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, overlay

so I want to create cross-platform app that will be invisible overlay over whole screen. When user interacts with whatever is under, I want to catch the event (mouse location, mouse click etc) so I can have info of what user attempted and where, and then "pass" the event through. Also, I might wanna display something in overlay as result of the event.

Coming from .NET, I understand how I would hook into mouse events. I also understand that it is possible to simulate user clicks with Mouse class in .NET Core. However I was wondering if this is possible with electron, as I was checking it for cross-platform solution.

I checked some topics (like this [click-through](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/23042) discussion) that mostly deal with passing events through overlay, but I am not sure those do this catching-then-passing. So is there something like that and is it actually possible with only electron/nodeJS? Or would I have to use additional libs, and would they be different for Win/Linux/Mac?

I checked at:
[Overlay Electron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35608927/overlay-electron) and
[electron-overlay-window](https://github.com/SnosMe/electron-overlay-window)
but both seem complicated with attaching to game and following the window respectively. I was hoping it is possible and simple somehow.

Comment: Actually, electron-overlay-window is very easy to use. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67110394/533976

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, it's is possible, but will require a ton of OS-specific code and possibly some native modules.

I suggest to start with https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#wingetnativewindowhandle and https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winsetignoremouseeventsignore-options